# Need to eliminate unnecessary duplicate files while regex is checking it

Tags: vbscript

```
Source="C:\\SourceDirectory"
Destination="C:\\DestinationDirectory"
pattern1="^"&"TestApp"&".*"&"zip"

Function RegExTest(pattern, stringToSearch)
    Dim regEx  ' Create variable.
    Set regEx = New RegExp    ' Create a regular expression.
    regEx.Pattern = pattern   ' Set pattern.
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True   ' Set case insensitivity.
    regEx.Global = True       ' Set global applicability.
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(stringToSearch)   ' Execute search.q
      IF Matches.count  > 0 Then
         RegExTest = True
      End IF
End Function 



Sub ProcessFile(Source, Destination)
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(Destination)
    If Not (Right(Destination, 1) = "\") Then
        Destination = Destination & "\"
    End If
    ' Deal with Duplicate Files
    Dim sourceArr, File
    sourceArr = Split(Source, "\")
    File = sourceArr(UBound(sourceArr))
    If Not FSO.FileExists(Destination & File) Then    
        returnValue = True
        For Each File In Folder.Files
            if RegExTest(pattern1,File.Name) And returnValue = "True" Then
                WScript.Echo("filename: "&File.Name&" filesize: "&File.Size)
            End If
        Next
        FSO.MoveFile Source, Destination
    End If  
End Sub
```

I have only 3 TestApp.zip files but I'm getting 9 files which is resulting false file size in total, Folder structure is like this[image]

*Any help much appreciated!! Thanks in advance*

Comment: In the code that you posted, I can't see this function RegExTest ?

Comment: @Hackoo we meet again :-)

Comment: You should look into regular expressions. "*" is not a wildcard like you seem to think.